# What are the rules for NWebSec.SessionSecurity authenticationKey attribute?

Tags: nwebsec

Specifically, the one indicated below:

```
  <nwebsec>
    <sessionSecurity xmlns="http://nwebsec.com/SessionSecurityConfig.xsd"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NWebsecConfig/SessionSecurityConfig.xsd">
      <sessionIDAuthentication enabled="true"
                               useMachineKey="false"
 ----------------------->      authenticationKey="64char hex string here"/>
    </sessionSecurity>
  </nwebsec>
```

My questions are:

- Should I change this value between different deployments of my site?
- Is this supposed to be a secret? (I assume so but this was not indicated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authenticationKey`is an alternative to using the `machineKey`, and should be treated similarly. I.e. you should use different keys for different enviroments, and you should also keep the key secret.

If you've configured the `machineKey` for your application, it's recommended to just use that. The `authenticationKey` was added to support scenarios where the `machineKey` couldn't be read from config.